# Checkbox Input doesn't work at all in chrome. Doesn't function in other browsers

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically I want a checkbox to onClick change whether or not to show explicit content.  I'll get right to the code 
 HTML (and PHP):

```
</form>
<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username']; 
    echo '
<form name="explicit">
<input type="checkbox" onClick="changeexplicit();" value="Filter Explicit Content"         id="explicitcheckbox" ' ;

    if (checkadult($mysqli,$username)!=1){echo "checked";}
    echo ' /> <label for="explicitcheckbox" class="explicit">Filter Explicit Content</label>
</form>';}?>
```

Jquery: (i left the error handling blank because I didn't realize JQuery doesn't have a built in popup alert)

```
<script>
changeexplicit()
{
!(function($){
   $(function() {   
        $.post('includes/changeadult.php', $('form[name="explicit"]').serialize(),   function(data){

          data = $.parseJSON(data);

          if(data.success){
          window.location.reload(true);
          }
          else if(data.error){
          }
          else{
          }
        });
});
})(window.jQuery);
}
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include_once 'db_connect.php';
include_once 'functions.php';

sec_session_start(); // Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.

$response = array();

if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
        $result=mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT isAdult FROM members WHERE username =         "'.$username.'"');
    $userinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $isAdult=$userinfo['isAdult'];
if ($isAdult==1)
{mysqli_query($mysqli,'UPDATE members SET isAdult=0 WHERE username="'.$username.'"');}
else{
    {mysqli_query($mysqli,'UPDATE members SET isAdult=1 WHERE username="'.$username.'"');}}

     $response['success'] = true;
}
else if(login_check($mysqli) == false) {
$response['error'] = true;
}
 echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: If you found the solution, write an answer and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function changeexplicit(){
    $.post('includes/changeadult.php', $('form[name="explicit"]').serialize(), function(data){
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        if(data.success){
            window.location.reload(true);
        }else if(data.error){
        }else{}
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: THANKS!  it works fine in IE now, but I still can't click the checkbox in chrome...

Answer (score 0):

Try change `onClick` to`onchange`?

Comment: Oh, soon then: 50 rep :-)